# Javascript onclick issue with a draggable div

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

If a create a div element with

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div')

newdiv.className = 'jsplumb-draggable _jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor_ jsplumb-drag'
```

(I use the  [jsplumb lib](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/draggableConnectors/dom.html))
and want to bind a onlick event with

```
newdiv.onclick = function(e) {
   console.log("ONCLICK FIRED!!")
   newdiv.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFF00 20%, #FF0000 100%"
}
```

I get a "strange" behavior with it.... i.e. the click event is fired but the codeblock inside the function prints on the console but chan
ges the color of the div ONLY IF I DRAG THE DIV, AND ONLY THE FIRST TIME!!
What could be the reason?

Comment: You know there is a typo here: `backgrundImage`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote here bad.... in my code it is write in right way, `backgroundImage`.....